# Python Selenium Package, selection of specific language

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

with selenium package for python I want to:
1. Identify element on webpage
2. Select language

I believe that presented below HTML code refers to the button I have in mind:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
        <li><a>Wersja:6653.606</a></li>
        <img src="Img/Flags/32/pl.png">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Wybór języka<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="Img/Flags/16/pl.png" style="margin-right: 10px">pl</a></li>
            <li><a href="Language?l=en&ReturnUrl=Login?"><img src="Img/Flags/16/en.png" style="margin-right: 10px">en</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logowanie</a></li>
      </ul>
```

This is dropdown list, which presents two options:

- polish language
- english language

**How do I locate this specific object on website (dropdown list)?** 

I was thinking about something like: 
select_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("dropdown-menu dropdown-user")

**How do I use webbrowser to select specific option? (Let's say english language)** 

Some sort of selection, but I have to find the element first.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It took me at least couple of hours to find the solution, but I did it :). 

To sum up: 
1. I need to select and click the listbox on website with language selection. 
2. Then I need to select and click desired language.

**Solution:** 
- You can find element (like listbox) with selenium on multiple different ways: 
    find_element_by_id 
    find_element_by_name 
    find_element_by_xpath 
    find_element_by_link_text 
    find_element_by_partial_link_text 
    find_element_by_tag_name 
    find_element_by_class_name 
    find_element_by_css_selector 
    Documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html 

- I tried multiple of them and failed. 
  I found info, that xpath is very reliable until somebody makes changes to html code of website. 
- I have 0 knowledge of html / css etc. thus finding xpath was very difficult for me. 

  
  Fortunately I found add-in to firefox which did it for me: 
  https://github.com/trembacz/xpath-finder 
- After installation of add-in, I first selected/found xpath for Listbox, then the same for language. 
- Python code for both elements:

```
    #Find Listbox with language selection and click it
    select_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/nav[1]/ul/li[2]/a")
    select_element.click()

    #Find language inside listbox and click it
    select_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/nav[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a")
    select_element.click()
```

Done :)